# Which is the original question for this duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

"[When to use val, def, and lazy val in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291831/when-to-use-def-val-and-lazy-val-in-scala)" was closed as a duplicate, but I'm having trouble determining which one was marked by the reviewers as the original question.
There are some links in the comments, but most are not by reviewers, and one even intends to show that this question is *not* a duplicate.

Comment: Back when the system injected the text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the asker edited out the text that linked to the duplicate.

Yes, that used to be possible.

I rolled the question back to the revision that showed it. Then re-opened it. Then re-closed it as a duplicate of a *different* question. Then merged it, implicitly locking it in the process. Thereby demonstrating why removing helpful edits from the system is a terrible idea if you don't want your question heavily annotated and locked.

Comment: This sounds like a lot of work for little benefit. Thank god for moderators willing to do this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Well, Shog9 has 200k meta rep (btw, congrats on that!) for a reason <3